# How can I use keyboard shortcuts to do a git commit and push from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, macos, git, intellij-idea

I'm aware that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (on macOS) will bring up the Git commit dialog, but I can't figure out how to do a commit and then a push without switching to my mouse.

Can anyone provide any guidance here?

Comment: For me (windows) I can use Ctrl+K, type commit message, Alt+P, enter, and then enter to push. Alt+P is to access the "Commit and Push" option of the commit changes dialog. Perhaps try that?

Comment: Ah, I thought I had experimented with "Alt" to trigger those keys, but I guess not.  Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> acts as an accelerator for the "Commit and Push" commit button option. On Mac it is <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

Another option is to just do the commit from the commit dialog using the default "commit" option. Then when it is done open the VCS Quick Menu (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Backquote (`)</kbd> for windows;  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Mac) and then do the push from there, either by number or narrowing down via inline search for "push"

Comment: Sorry for the cross post with @Kyptic's comment. I started typing this up before he posted, but got side-tracked in an IM chat, then came back to post.

Comment: That's ok, your answer is more elaborate and nicely formatted.  I'll upvote his comment also.

Answer (score 8):

In the commit dialogue, press <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> to bring up the options, and <kbd>return</kbd> to commit.

Answer (score 3):

After analyzing all these answers above, I wasn't satisfied and I found following solution:

1. Open commit dialog <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.
2. Type your commit message.
3. Switch to commit button <kbd>Tab</kbd>
4. Press button <kbd>Space</kbd>